# how to return typed value

Tags: typescript, class, typing

i have this function that randomize 3 strings, but when i try to return the value, i got this error

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"DAY" | "GTD" | "GTC"'

my function:

```js
export const randomizeTimeinforce = (): 'DAY' | 'GTD' | 'GTC' => {
  const timeinforce = ['DAY', 'GTD', 'GTC'];
  return timeinforce[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
};


export class MyCoolClass {
  public timeinforce: 'DAY' | 'GTD' | 'GTC' = randomizeTimeinforce();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add a so called [const assertion](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/const-assertions-in-literal-expressions-in-typescript) to avoid TS interpreting your `timeinforce` array as `string[]`. This latter (default) behavior is also called type widening and is something you want to avoid here...

```
export const randomizeTimeinforce = () => {
  const timeinforce = <const>['DAY', 'GTD', 'GTC'];
  return timeinforce[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
};


export class MyCoolClass {
  public timeinforce = randomizeTimeinforce();
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=52#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7ygQ2QEwgWwEsAvYAFUP2EOQDNoFg4BeOACgEoWA%20OAbwBQcRCnRwYlanQZNWAHiRoY3ANoByACIBBAJpqANHDUBxMhoNHTAYTUBdANxC4UYDACuUZOMk16URioAspgwABYAdLQANhDQbMFh4Vi4BJxwAFRwAMwcDgIAvo4CAqCQsIhRmKiocIEAnlaxUVaV1fxOYG4ARlGECN5UvjIszth4RKQUg9L%20wJyO%20UA)

Comment: works, but i got this error in my console:
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'const'

Comment: @Igor you must be using an old version of TS - const assertions were added in 3.4 (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) - I've also added a playground link, where you can try it out w/ different TS versions...